# Why doesn't by_ref prevent .all from consuming the iterator?

Tags: rust

The following prints `9`, then `true`, as expected:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = (1..10);
    println!("{}", a.by_ref().count()); // 9
    println!("{}", a.all(|x| x < 10)); // true
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=84ce895c02977281d5e6ebb8ea1cd167)

The following prints `true` then `0`!

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = (1..10);
    println!("{}", a.by_ref().all(|x| x < 10)); // true
    println!("{}", a.count()); // 0
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5779d29ad9dd74a43c62d5f073ef1d04)

**Shouldn't calling `.by_ref()` on the iterator before calling `.all` prevent `.all` from consuming the iterator?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other answers cover what's going on implementation-wise, but I'd like to address the terminology, which I think lies at the root of the confusion:

> Shouldn't calling `.by_ref()` on the iterator before calling `.all` prevent `.all` from consuming the iterator?

In Rust **consume** has a narrow definition related to ownership - a function "consuming" a value takes ownership of the value from the caller. Since the function is free to destroy the value or pass it along, the value is unavailable for further use by the caller that owned it originally.

In case of values implementing `Iterator`, methods that consume them, such as `count()` or `sum()`, typically also exhaust them (use them up). Other methods, such as `map()` or `enumerate()`, consume the iterator and return a new iterator, which will exhaust the original one provided that it is exhausted itself. But there are also methods like [`take()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take) or [`scan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan), which consume the iterator without necessarily exhausting it, even when the iterator they return is fully exhausted. With such methods `by_ref()` comes in handy to keep the original iterator available for further processing:

```
let mut iter = 1..1000;
let sum_first_50 = iter.by_ref().take(50).sum();
let sum_second_50 = iter.by_ref().take(50).sum();
// ... iter available to produce the remaining 899 numbers ...
```

Without the `by_ref()` in the first line, the second line wouldn't compile because the first `take()` would *consume* (but not *exhaust*) `iter`. With `by_ref()` `iter` is neither consumed (because `by_ref()` protects it) nor exhausted (because we combined it with `take()`). Combining `by_ref()` with a method that both consumes and exhausts the iterator, such as `count()`, is well-defined but useless, because it will just leave you in possession of an exhausted iterator.

If you want to prevent the iterator from getting exhausted (or otherwise mutated), you can instead clone it:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 1..10;
    println!("{}", a.clone().all(|x| x < 10)); // true
    println!("{}", a.count()); // 9
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling `all()` or `count()` on an iterator will invoke `next()` many times.
Even if the iterator is not consumed (moved-from), its internal state has changed due to the repetitive invocations of `next()`.

When `all()` ends with `true`, the end of the sequence has been reached, thus `count()` is still callable but yields `0`.

In the first case, `count()` reaches the end of the sequence, but the [documentation of `all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) says that `true` is returned for an empty sequence.

Comment: Ah, that's helpful, so in the first example, all isn't even looping through the elements because it's already exhausted, yet it returns true anyway.  Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Every iterator adapter (such as `.take`, `.filter`, and of course, `.all`) only have access to the elements of the iterator through the `.next` function.

The only thing that `.by_ref` does is that it allows you to continue using the iterator after the use of iterator adapters on it. Any consumed element will still be consumed. If you don't want that, you  should clone the iterator instead.

This is explained in the documentation for Iterator::by_ref:

```rust
let a = [1, 2, 3];

let iter = a.iter();

let sum: i32 = iter.take(5).fold(0, |acc, i| acc + i);

assert_eq!(sum, 6);

// if we try to use iter again, it won't work. The following line
// gives "error: use of moved value: `iter`
// assert_eq!(iter.next(), None);

// let's try that again
let a = [1, 2, 3];

let mut iter = a.iter();

// instead, we add in a .by_ref()
let sum: i32 = iter.by_ref().take(2).fold(0, |acc, i| acc + i);

assert_eq!(sum, 3);

// now this is just fine:
assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some(&3));
assert_eq!(iter.next(), None);
```